# Row and Column rotation matrices

Tags: matrices, rotations

Today I started studying Rotation matrices and derived a rotation matrix like this:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
       x & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(\beta) & \sin(\beta)  \\
        -\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) 
        \end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

When I was googling for the solution to check if this was ok, I found almost everybody expressed it like this:

\begin{equation*}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(\beta) & -\sin(\beta)  \\
        \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation*}

If I'm not mistaken, this leads to the same equations, but is there anything else special about expressing it in these 2 different forms? Has this something to do with  Handedness?

Comment: Your annotations are correct. The handedness can be inferred from the determinant of your rotation matrix (left-hand coordinate system if negative.)
As for the different formats, it depends on what type of storage your vectors use; either column or row -wise that you select to pre or post -multiply for your rotations

Comment: Ok, I see, so as a conclusion: The way I express this matrix operation has nothing to do with handeness (I mean, use row or column matrix). The handeness is given by the determinat. Could you confirm this?

Comment: confirmed as @Ridac asserts

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The difference is that you used a row vector and the other expression uses a column vector. And they are the same if you transpose one of them. 
\begin{align}
\left( 
\begin{pmatrix}
       x & y
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(\beta) & \sin(\beta)  \\
        -\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) 
\end{pmatrix}
\right)^T
&=
\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(\beta) & \sin(\beta)  \\
        -\sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) 
\end{pmatrix}
^T
\begin{pmatrix}
       x & y
\end{pmatrix}
^T
\\ &=
\begin{pmatrix}
        \cos(\beta) & -\sin(\beta)  \\
        \sin(\beta) & \cos(\beta) 
\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}
      x \\ y
\end{pmatrix}
\end{align}